# Failed to resolve: com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:1.5.0

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

**Gradle Sync Failed after adding:**

> Error: Failed to resolve:
>   com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:1.5.0

```
def appCenterSdkVersion = '1.5.0'
implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
implementation "com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:${appCenterSdkVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this to my Gradle at the very bottom:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I believe it is because my gradle is very old and possibly not standard.